# Query with multimatch and wildcard

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, wildcard, nest

I'm trying to execute a query on multi fields but also using a wildcard in the MobileNumber, basically, if a mobile number is for example 3530831112233 if I search by 831122 I want to return this record. This is what I have done so far.

```
var response = await this.client.SearchAsync<ElasticCustomer>(searchDescriptor => searchDescriptor
          .AllTypes()
            .Query(q => q
                     .MultiMatch(m => m
                            .Fields(f => f
                                .Field(u => u.CustomerName)
                                .Field(u => u.MobileNumber))
                          .Query(query)))
          .Size(pageSize)
          .Sort(q => q.Descending(u => u.CustomerLastUpdated)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform wildcard query, you will need to use something like [wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) and combine it with match query on `CustomerName` field in a [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

Here is the simple app showing usage:

```
class Program
{
    public class Document  
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    } 

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
        var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool);
        connectionSettings.DefaultIndex("documents");

        var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

        await client.Indices.DeleteAsync("documents");
        await client.Indices.CreateAsync("documents");

        var response = await client.IndexAsync(
            new Document
            {
                Id = 1, 
                Timestamp = new DateTime(2010, 01, 01, 10, 0, 0),
                MobileNumber = "3530831112233",
                CustomerName = "Robert"
            }, descriptor => descriptor);

        await client.Indices.RefreshAsync();

        string query = "8311122";
        var result = await client.SearchAsync<Document>(s => s
            .Query(q => q.Bool(b => b
                .Should(
                    sh => sh.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.CustomerName).Query(query)),
                    sh => sh.Wildcard(w => w.Field(f => f.MobileNumber.Suffix("keyword")).Value($"*{query}*"))))));

        foreach (var document in result.Documents)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(document.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
```

However, I would suggest avoiding the wildcard query whenever you can at it maybe result in query performance degradation.

As a wildcard substitution, you can have a look at [ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_ngrams_for_partial_matching.html#_ngrams_for_partial_matching) or [phone number analyzer plugin](https://github.com/purecloudlabs/elasticsearch-phone).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sure I will investigate the phone number analyzer plugin.
Another issue I'm facing is duplicate records, for example, I have two records for the same customer but with different customerLastUpdated dates, there is a way to return only the most recent one?

Comment: Maybe create a separate issue with simple reproduction so people can have a look at try to help.